# Задать tile size для arcgis

Tags: gis

Необходимо кешировать запросы к публичной кадастровой карте, которая работает на ArcGis MapServer.

С недавних пор, росреестр ограничил `tile size` в запросах на `[1024, 1024]`.
Если приходит другое, то запрос не обрабатывается.

Каким образом в MapProxy, в настройках ArcGis, можно установить tile size, который будет передаваться в запросе?

Настройки типа:

```
  pkk5_arcgis:
    type: arcgis
    req:
      url: http://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/Cadastre/MapServer/export?
      layers: 'show: 0,1'
      transparent: true
      dpi: 96
      size: [1024, 1024]
```

порождают сообщения:  `mapproxy.config - WARNING - unknown 'size' in sources.pkk5_arcgis.req`. Хотя в исходниках есть комментарий, в котором говорится, что параметр `size` поддерживается.

```
opts:
  size: [1024, 1024]
```

порождает такое же сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явным образом задать размер нельзя, для запроса он рассчитывается из параметров meta_size (значение по умолчанию [4,4]), meta_buffer (значение 80) секции cache и tile_size (по умолчанию [256,256]), т.е. размер по одному измерению по умолчанию получается как meta_size*tile_size+2*meta_buffer=4*256+2*80=1184
Для искомого значения 1024 нужно соответственно поменять параметр[ы]

Работающий вариант:

```
caches:
   pkk_cache:
     grids: [webmercator]
     sources: [pkk5_arcgis]
     meta_buffer: 0
```

И да - в запросе к ПКК нужно кодировать (quote) запятые (',' -> '%2C'), для этого нужно внести изменение в исходный код:

`request/base.py:373:            kv_pairs.append(key + '=' + quote(value.encode('utf-8') )) #, safe=','))`